# How to access to a class's property without an instance?

Tags: javascript

Currently, I have a class of this sort:

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor(privateInfo) {
    this.a = "a";
    this.b = "b";
  }

  myMethod() {
    return privateInfo;
  }
}
```

As you can see `privateInfo` need to be "get" but not defined in the constructor.

Private properties would not work, because if I stringify the object, the property is also in the string, and I don't want it there.

Is there any way to achieve this? Not necessarily a complete solution but some hints would be enough.

Comment: If the property is not enumerable it will not be included in the result of `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: that was enlightening, thank you

Comment: What if you make it `static`?

Comment: As @MenaiAlaEddine-Aladdin says, `static` is pretty much defined as belonging to the class but not the instance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use `static` Keyword :

**MDN Documentation :**

> Static properties cannot be directly accessed on instances of the
> class. Instead, they're accessed on the class itself.
>
> Static methods are often utility functions, such as functions to
> create or clone objects, whereas static properties are useful for
> caches, fixed-configuration, or any other data you don't need to be
> replicated across instances.

### Example

```js
class Student {
  name: string;
  static age: number;
  constructor(age: number) {
    this.name = 'Jhon';
    Student.age = age;
  }
  static getAge = () => Student.age;
}

const student = new Student(20);

const json = JSON.stringify(student); // {"name":"Jhon"}
console.log(json);
console.log(Student.getAge()); // 20
```

### Your code:

```js
class MyClass {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  static c: string;
  constructor(c:string) {
    this.a = 'a';
    this.b = 'b';
    MyClass.c = c;
  }
  myMethod() {
    return MyClass.c;
  }
}
const obj = new MyClass('hi'); 
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); // {"a":"a","b":"b"}
console.log(obj.myMethod()); // hi
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the edit, I didn't accept just because private makes more semantic sense to me, but I appreciated it.

Answer (score 3):

> Private properties would not work, because if I stringify the object, the property is also in the string

No it's not? This works fine:

```js
class MyClass {
  #c;
  constructor(c) {
    this.a="a";
    this.b="b";
    this.#c=c;
  }
  myMethod() {
    return this.#c;
  }
}
const obj = new MyClass('hi');
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
console.log(obj.myMethod());
```

An alternative would be to create the method in the constructor, as a closure over the `c` variable:

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor(c) {
    this.a="a";
    this.b="b";
    this.myMethod = () => {
      return c;
    };
  }
}
const obj = new MyClass('hi');
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
console.log(obj.myMethod());
```

Further alternatives that work with normal properties and prevent inclusion in the `JSON.stringify` result are to make the `c` property non-enumerable or to define a custom `toJSON` method.

Answer (score 0):

In my real world class I added the properties:

```js
class MyClass{

  //other props
  preQ: string;
  postQ: string;

  constructor(data: InputData = { cli: cli.flags }) {
    Object.defineProperties(this, {
      preQ: { enumerable: false },
      postQ: { enumerable: false },
    });
    // other stuff
 }
}
```

As indicated to in the first comment by Pointy. The properties are not present in the `JSON.stringify` result.

Which are properties that I do not want to be sent to the server.